# How to stop TextField from accepting input - AWT

Tags: java, eclipse, awt

I have a textField in which I input a username, and I want the screen to change when the 'enter' key is pressed. But what I noticed is that the KeyPressed method doesn't start, because the enter key is taken as input into the textfield.

Is there a way for me to loose focus on a TextField when the enter key is pressed, even if the KeyPressed method doesn't work while focused on the textfield?

Comment: This might help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html

Comment: [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use an ordinary event handler like this:

```
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
```

A TextField action is different from a button action. A TextField action checks the Enter key for any actions, unlike a button, which checks for input through the mouse.